# Heuristic completion: outcome state is mixed inside Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have two databases and set up for chainedTransactionManager.
I've faced a strange error while executing saveAll in both databases. That logic executes in spring schedule job.

```
 @Transactional(value = "chainedTransactionManager")
 public void migrateData() {
       migrate();
 }

 private void migrate() {
  var assignments = assignmentsRepository.findTop10ByIsMigratedFalse();
  assignments.forEach(it -> it.isMigrated = true);
  assignmentsRepository.saveAll(assignments);
  assignmentsMysqlRepository.saveAll(assignments);
 }
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is mixed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update assignment set ismigrated=?, humanentity=? where humankey=? and assignmentlist=?; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update assignment set ismigrated=?, humanentity=? where humankey=? and legallist=?
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:195)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.test.human.assigment.migration.AssignmentJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6eaedbba.migrate(<generated>)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update assignment set ismigrated=?, humanentity=? where humankey=? and assigmentlist=?; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update assignment set ismigrated=?, humanentity=? where humankey=? and assigmentlist=?
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update assignment set ismigrated=?, humanentity=? where humankey=? and assigmentlist=?
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3571)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3438)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    ... 26 more
```

Could someone know how to handle that issue?

Comment: Can you turn on SQL logging and post the result queries for both databases?

Comment: Please share the `Assingment` entity definition. This looks like it could be related to optimistic locking issues. Either way, I would suggest you use `@Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` on the `findTop10ByIsMigratedFalse` method, since you are about to update these entities.